# Is there a bottleneck when accessing "original" registers on an i7?

Tags: performance, optimization, x86, intel, cpu-architecture

## Short version:

On the Intel i7, is there some sort of bottleneck in accessing the "original" registers (`eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`) that is not present in the "new" registers (`r8d`, `r9d`, etc.)? I'm timing some code, and, if I try to run three add instructions in parallel, I can get a CPI of .33, as long as only two of the three adds reference an "original" register (e.g., I use `eax`, `ebx`, and `r9d`).  If I try to use three "original" registers, the CPI goes up to about .4.  I observed is on both an i7-3770 and an i7-4790.

## The details:

I trying to develop a new (hopefully interesting) lab for my Computer Architecture class. The goal is for them to time some assembly code on an Intel i7 processor and observe things like (a) the throughput of the processor, and (b) the consequences of data dependencies.

When I try to write some assembly code that exhibits an average CPI of .33 (i.e., demonstrates that the CPU can maintain a throughput of 3 instructions per cycle), I find that this is only possible if at most two of the three instructions access the "original" general purpose registers.

## Experiment setup

Here is the basic outline of the experiment:  Use `rdtsc` to time segments of a few thousand instructions, then plot the "cycle count" against the number of instructions timed to estimate the throughput.  For example, running this code inside of a loop

```
    mov $0, %eax
    cpuid
    rdtsc
    movl    %eax, %r12d
    addl    $1, %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    # the line above is copied "n" times 
    # (I use a ruby script to generate this part of the assembly)
    addl    $1, %eax

    rdtsc
    subl    %r12d, %eax
```

allows us to report how long (in reference cycles) it takes to run a sequence of `n` `addl` instructions.  (The segment of code above is part of a longer program that repeats the measurement many times, throws out the first few thousand trials, and reports the lowest and/or most common result.)

## Results that makes sense

When I time a sequence of adds to a single register, I get the expected result:

```
instructions    elapsed reference ref cycles       estimated actual  actual cycles
between rdtsc   cycles            per instruction  cycles            per instruction
     200           145             0.72                169             0.84
     300           220             0.73                256             0.85
     400           314             0.79                365             0.91
     500           408             0.82                474             0.95
     600           483             0.81                562             0.94
     700           577             0.82                671             0.96
     800           652             0.81                758             0.95
     900           746             0.83                867             0.96
    1000           840             0.84                977             0.98
    1100           915             0.83               1064             0.97
    1200          1009             0.84               1173             0.98
    ........................................................................
    3500          3019             0.86               3510             1.00
    3600          3094             0.86               3598             1.00
    3700          3188             0.86               3707             1.00
    3800          3282             0.86               3816             1.00
    3900          3357             0.86               3903             1.00
    4000          3451             0.86               4013             1.00
```

After converting reference cycles to (estimated) actual cycles, the processor averages about one instruction per cycle.  This makes sense because every timed instruction depends on the previous instruction, thereby preventing parallel execution. Notice that we do not issue a serializing instruction before ending `rdtsc`.  As a result, the last few dozen timed instructions are not yet complete when we "stop" the timer. Consequently, the CPI for the first few rows of this table is artificially low. The effects of this "undercount" limit to zero as the number of instructions timed increases.

If we modify the timed code to alternate between additions to `eax` and `ebx`, we also get the expected result:  A CPI that tends toward 0.5:

```
    mov $0, %eax
    cpuid
    rdtsc
    movl    %eax, %r12d

    addl    $1, %eax
    addl    $1, %ebx

    addl    $1, %eax
    addl    $1, %ebx

    # the pair of lines above are copied until there are `n` lines total being timed

    addl    $1, %eax
    addl    $1, %ebx

    rdtsc
    subl    %r12d, %eax

instructions    elapsed reference ref cycles       estimated actual  actual cycles
between rdtsc   cycles            per instruction  cycles            per instruction
    1000           432             0.43                502             0.50
    1200           510             0.42                593             0.49
    1400           601             0.43                699             0.50
    1600           695             0.43                808             0.51
    1800           773             0.43                899             0.50
    2000           864             0.43               1005             0.50
    2200           955             0.43               1110             0.50
```

## Question:  Why does it matter which register I use when trying to run 3 instructions in parallel?

When I try to run adds to `eax`, `ebx`, and `ecx` in parallel, the CPI is higer than the expected .33:

```
    mov $0, %eax
    cpuid
    rdtsc
    movl    %eax, %r12d

   addl    $1, %eax
   addl    $1, %ebx
   addl    $1, %ecx

   addl    $1, %eax
   addl    $1, %ebx
   addl    $1, %ecx

   # the group of lines above are copied until there are `n` lines total being timed

   addl    $1, %eax
   addl    $1, %ebx
   addl    $1, %ecx

   rdtsc
   subl    %r12d, %eax


instructions    elapsed reference ref cycles       estimated actual  actual cycles
between rdtsc   cycles            per instruction  cycles            per instruction
    1200           408             0.34                474             0.40
    1500           492             0.33                572             0.38
    1800           595             0.33                692             0.38
    2100           698             0.33                812             0.39
    2400           782             0.33                909             0.38
    2700           885             0.33               1029             0.38
    3000           988             0.33               1149             0.38
    3300          1091             0.33               1269             0.38
    3600          1178             0.33               1370             0.38
```

However, I get the expected result if I use `r9d`, `r10d`, and `r11d`:

```
instructions    elapsed reference ref cycles       estimated actual  actual cycles
between rdtsc   cycles            per instruction  cycles            per instruction
    1200           350             0.29                407             0.34
    1500           444             0.30                516             0.34
    1800           519             0.29                603             0.34
    2100           613             0.29                713             0.34
    2400           707             0.29                822             0.34
    2700           782             0.29                909             0.34
    3000           876             0.29               1019             0.34
```

In fact, I get the expected result as long as at most two of the three registers come from the set `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, and `edx`. Why is that? Any idea whether the bottleneck is in the issue, decoding, register renaming, or retirement?

I observed this behavior on both an i7-3770 and an i7-4790.  For what it's worth: Both the Ryzen 7 and i5-6500 always have CPIs of .38 to .40, regardless of the registers used.

---

## The code

For those who are curious, here is the template for the code I use:

```
.file   "timestamp_shell.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .string "%8d; Start %10u; Stop %10u; Difference %5d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %r13
    pushq   %r12
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_offset 13, -24
    .cfi_offset 12, -32
    .cfi_offset 3, -40
    movl    $100, %r12d
    movl    $200, %r13d
    movl    $-1, %r8d
    movl    $0, %r8d
    jmp .L2
    .L3:
    mov $0, %eax
    cpuid
    rdtsc
    movl    %eax, %r12d
    movl $0, %eax

    # I use a perl script to copy the lines marked with #@ until there
    # is the desired number of instructions between the calls to rdstc

    #@    addl $1, %eax
    #@    addl $1, %r10d
    #@    addl $1, %ecx

    rdtsc
    subl    %r12d, %eax
    movl    %eax, %r8d
    movl    %r13d, %ecx
    movl    %r12d, %edx
    movl    %r8d, %esi
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
    addl    $1, %r8d
.L2:
    cmpl    $999999, %r8d
    jle .L3
    movl    $199, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r12
    popq    %r13
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.2.1 20181127"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: 1.5k or more insns won't fit in the uop cache, and will run from the legacy decoders, but your 1.2k test might hit. On IvyBridge the back-end bottlenecks at 0.33c throughput for `add`. That bottleneck should hide any front-end bubbles from decode, so your IvB results are definitely interesting. But Haswell (including your i7-4790) has a 4th ALU port (port 6), so the back-end can keep up with the front-end issue bottleneck of 4 uops / clock. Then you have to worry about other front-end bottlenecks, like 4-wide decode or uop-cache fetch, so how your code packs into uop cache could matter on HSW.

Comment: With the larger instructions (REX prefix) being faster, it's not going to be anything simple like pre-decode slowdowns with 8x 2-byte instructions per 32-byte block, which would lead to a pre-decode pattern of 6 uops / 2 uops.  (https://agner.org/optimize/).  3-byte or 4-byte instructions should decode efficiently.  Have you used HW performance counters to measure where the bottleneck is?  Presumably it's the back-end stalling from RS full either way on IvB?  Does anything change if you use more than 3 regs so your IvB doesn't bottleneck on dep chains as well as ALU port throughput?

Comment: And BTW, performance counters would let you measure the total time for `n` repeats *in core clock cycles*, avoiding the need to convert from ref cycles to core cycles.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the same behavior on Haswell. With three `add` chains, the throughput is about 0.38 irrespective of which registers are used. You can share the whole code and I'll try to use the same exact code on my system.

Comment: Have you tried recording timings into an array, instead of calling `printf` every iteration?  Or redirecting output to a file would make stdout full-buffered instead of line-buffered, avoiding making a system call every iteration.  IDK why a system call could make anything *faster*, but returning from a system call with potential I-cache misses might change things.